# Xdebug on ubuntu and phpStorm doesn't show any erros

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

So I am new in ubuntu and I installed LAMP and get it to work with phpsotrm properly. The only problem i have is that when i have errors in my code it doesn't  show me any errors, just a blank page.

Now with phpstorm I manged to connect with xDebug and when I checked phpinfo() I found:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BimHD.jpg

Here is the phpstorm connection:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2boeY.jpg

I changed proper php.ini file and I added following line at the end of the file:

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
;xdebug.remote_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_port="9000"
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

Still noting is shown, not even in the console or in the page source. Is there any fix for this issue? I tried to search the internet but couldn't find anything.

Comment: ; means comment. Your lines are not taking any effect, unless you remove the leading ; (semicolon)

Comment: I tried what you told me still nothing happened but i just noticed that in the console of php storm it is giveing me the following error.

POST http://localhost:63342/File%20Repository/Controller/folders.php 500 (Internal Server Error) folders.php

Comment: Now you are getting somewhere. 500 means a problem in your php code.

Comment: know thatbut comeing from windows it used to give a orange table sayin what the error is/
It is not like that in ubuntu?

Comment: I'm lost there, can't give you a real answer to your question, sorry

Comment: So i used to program on a windows machine and when ever i used to make en error on the code i used to get an orange table on the page (Browser) discribing the error, and i used xdebug aswell.

This doesnt happen on an ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow those intructions:

[Let PHP show all errors](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors)

It seems that you've got disabled showing any errors.

Comment: No it didnt work and i have them enabled by defult in the ini file anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I am such a  dummy it actually works just the certain errors that i was trying to simulated didn't really effect xDebug.
I am so sorry for wasting your time.